Linkedin Profile Tag from external social planner tool
I am writing to request assistance regarding scheduling posts through an external tool.
While using the external tool for scheduling posts on social media, specifically on the LinkedIn platform, I have noticed that when I insert the post text and want to mention someone, I can only mention company pages and not individuals.
I have contacted the tool's support, which informed me that this is a limitation imposed by the LinkedIn API.
I seek your support to know if the accessible rendering of this option/functionality is planned.
I look forward to your feedback,
Thanks
